# Changing the project name displayed on a G Suite app

Tags: g-suite

I created a project name for my G Suite app. Now that I am ready to beta-release the app, I have decided to name the app differently. However, the name displayed on the app still reflects the project name. Is there a way to change the name displayed or changed the project name for the project on the Google Cloud account?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#updating_projects

Comment: Thanks - I did make the edits to change the name on the project. But, the old name still shows up on the app.

Comment: I'd contact support, then.